# Email with laravel SMTP of Godaddy account fails?

Tags: laravel, email

I am trying to send an email in laravel with godaddy account but I always get an error

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
>   Expected response code 250 but got code "501", with message "501 HELO requires valid address"

Below code I used for the sending the email in controller:

```
$title = 'Test email';
$content = 'Test email from shingora';

Mail::send('emails.send', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content], function ($message) {

    $message->from('robin.shingora@gmail.com', 'Shingora');
    $message->subject('Test email');

    $message->to('robin.shingora@gmail.com');
});
```

And in mail.php

```
return [
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtpout.asia.secureserver.net',
'port' => 25,
'from' => ['address' => 'example@gmail.com', 'name' => 'test'],
'encryption' => 'ssl',
'username' => 'example@gmail.com',
'password' => '********',
'sendmail' => 'D:\sendmail\sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set all smtp setting in your .env file 
i.e

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=ssl://smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

OR

```
return [

'driver' => 'smtp',

'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',

'port' => 465,

'from' => ['address' => 'example@gmail.com', 'name' => 'test'],

'encryption' => 'ssl',

'username' => 'example@gmail.com',

'password' => '********',

'sendmail' => 'D:\sendmail\sendmail -bs',

 'pretend' => false,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Few weeks ago I had same issue and I solved the problem by realising that GoDaddy likes to have your from and reply-to e-mail should belong to your own domain.

And it may be a problem with your hostname, so I've browsed to another SO question and found this:

[Configure SwiftMailer "Local Domain" setting easily, in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562037/configure-swiftmailer-local-domain-setting-easily-in-symfony-2)

Comment: Have same issue, but in my case sender email( from email) belongs to the own domain. Please suggest some solution.